# Equation for the trajectory of a positively charged particle fired towards an atomic nucleus

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, scattering, coulombs-law

I'm interested in finding (or rather the mathematical approach to finding) an equation for the trajectory of a particle with charge $+q\space$  fired toward a stationary nucleus, i.e. the 'height' ($y$) of the particle above the beam from which it originated as a function of the horizontal distance to the nucleus ($x$). For Rutherford scattering, the trajectory should be a hyperbola.

I started by computing the kinetic energy (plus the energy at $-\infty$, $E$) of the particle: $T=\displaystyle \int \vec{F} \cdot \vec{dr} = \displaystyle \int \vec{F} \cdot (1,y'(x)) \space dx + E $

By Coulomb's law, the force repelling the two charges is $\vec{F}=\frac{k}{r^2} \hat{\mathbf{r}}=\frac{k}{r^2}(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta))= \frac{k}{x^2+y^2}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(y')^2}},\frac{y'}{\sqrt{1+(y')^2}})=\frac{k}{(x^2+y^2)\sqrt{1+(y')^2}}(1,y')$

$\Longrightarrow T=k \displaystyle \int \frac{1+(y')^2}{(x^2+y^2)\sqrt{1+(y')^2}} \space dx$

The Lagrangian for the particle is $\mathcal{L(x,y(x),y'(x))} = T-V =  k \displaystyle \int \frac{1+(y')^2}{(x^2+y^2)\sqrt{1+(y')^2}} \space dx - \frac{k}{q\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = k \displaystyle \int \frac{1+(y')^2}{(x^2+y^2)\sqrt{1+(y')^2}} + \frac{yy'+x}{q(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}} \space dx $

I then applied the Euler-Lagrange equation to the above functional, to obtain the ODE $\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx} (\frac{y'}{(x^2+y^2)\sqrt{1+(y')^2}}+\frac{y}{q(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}})=\frac{x^2y'-3xy-2y'y^2}{q(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{5}{2}}}-\frac{y\sqrt{1+(y')^2}}{(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$, which I don't believe is solvable by hand.

However, I'm not sure if my approach is mathematically sound, or if it betrays a fundamental misunderstanding of the physics of the problem. Also, I don't know how to plot this ODE in Maple as the initial conditions aren't quite clear to me: obviously, $y \rightarrow 0$ (or $b$, the impact parameter, if $y$ is taken to be the height from the center of the nucleus) as $x \rightarrow -\infty $, but how do you incorporate these into the program? The odd-looking plot that I do get by inputting any other set of random initial conditions doesn't really resemble a hyperbola to me in the slightest:

[image]

I appreciate any help or advice.

Comment: You have to be careful how you parametrize your path. You assume that you can use x as a parameter instead of the usual time t. The specific example you give at the end (i.e. initial conditions involve $y=0$) shows that this is not possible. What do you expect the trajectory to look like if the particle shoots straight at the nucleus?

Comment: What about using $y \rightarrow b$ as $x \rightarrow -\infty$, where $b$ is the impact parameter, and $y$ is measured from above the nucleus instead? Also, I used distance as a parameter because I'm ultimately looking for how $y$ varies with the distance to the nucleus, not time. If this is wrong, how do you suggest I should parameterize the trajectory?

Thanks

Comment: Yes it would make sense to look at those cases separately. But back to the problem: In the Lagrange formalism, remember which variation is zero. That of the Lagrangian or something else?

Comment: Yes, I should have varied the action of the system, not the Lagrangian! Thanks for pointing that out - quite a silly mistake on my part.

Comment: $\begin{aligned}\left( dr\right) ^{2}=\left( dx\right) ^{2}+\left( dy\right) ^{2}\\
dr=\sqrt{1+\left( \dfrac{dy}{dx}\right) ^{2}}dx\end{aligned}$